# Horizontal gradient stripe using background-size not working in IE9

Tags: css, background, filter, internet-explorer-9, gradient

I'm generating a bar of horizontal gradient as a background across my site that works perfectly in every browser except...IE9.

The gradient itself is working, it is just that I want to limit the height of the blue bar. Check it out in Safari/Firefox/Chrome and then in IE9 and you can see that the blue gradient fills the entire element.

[Horizontal gradient bar using CSS](http://solaslite.wpengine.com)

Here is my CSS:

```
#inner {
background: #1e5799;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #0057be 35%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(35%,#0057be));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#0057be 35%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#0057be 35%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#0057be 35%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#0057be 35%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#0057be',GradientType=0 );
background-size: 1px 10%;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 1em 0;
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing it's because your gradient is css made, so for the background-size property to work in IE9 you have to have an image background/color background. So `filter` is diffrent from `background` in IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work on IE9:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZzEiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjMWU1Nzk5Ii8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwLjM1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjMDA1N2JlIi8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2cxKSIgLz48L3N2Zz4=);
```

I made it with [Visual CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.visualcsstools.com/)

---

Updated CSS:

```
#inner {
background: #1e5799;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZzEiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjMWU1Nzk5Ii8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwLjM1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjMDA1N2JlIi8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2cxKSIgLz48L3N2Zz4=);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(0%, #1e5799), color-stop(35%, #0057be));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #0057be 35%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #0057be 35%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #0057be 35%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #0057be 35%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #0057be 35%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#0057be',GradientType=0 );
background-size: 1px 10%;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 1em 0;
}
```

---

IE9 doesn't support CSS3 gradients, but it supports inline SVG. I don't recommend to mix up `filter` and SVG backgrounds on IE9, i think the best approach is to use conditional comments as explained in [this article by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

Comment: Yep, you can't see any effects of the `background-size` property, because you didn't have a background specified in MS IE. A MS filter is not a background…

Comment: 99% of the way there Giona, I just had to make a few modifications to your code by removing filter altogether and adding border: 0.